Blender 3.5.1, using bpy how can I get Color Attribute, Render Color name?
as the question mentions, I want to get the name of the Render=On vertex color.
I can get the index using attributes
bpy.context.object.data.attributes.render_color_index

and set it using the name and index too
bpy.ops.geometry.color_attribute_render_set(name="Color.001")
bpy.context.object.data.attributes.render_color_index=0  # 0th index is Color.001

but don't know how can I get the name of the render color.
I already know how to get the active_color_index and active_color_name. but I can't seem to find how to get the render_color_name or something similar.

render color is the Color Attribute, below UV maps in Object data properties.
The render color basically turns on the render for the vertex color. It is different from active color. The active color is the selected vertex.
Indexing the .attributes[] directly, since its of type bpy_collection
 objdata = bpy.context.object.data
 selected_attrib = objdata.attributes[objdata.attributes.render_color_index]
    print(selected_attrib.name)


Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips and code only posts  rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.
